# unable to read content of the file which is written using the diffferent method

Tags: python

I want to read the content of the file which was written to the file by different function

```
from subprocess import *
import os
def compile():
    f=open("reddy.txt","w+")
    p=Popen("gcc -c rahul.c ",stdout=f,shell=True,stderr=STDOUT) #i have even tried with with open but it is not working,It is working with r+ but it is appending to file.
    f.close()   

def run():
    p1=Popen("gcc -o r.exe rahul.c",stdout=PIPE,shell=True,stderr=PIPE)
    p2=Popen("r.exe",stdout=PIPE,shell=True,stderr=PIPE)
    print(p2.stdout.read())
    p2.kill()

compile()
f1=open("reddy.txt","w+")    
first_char=f1.readline() #unable to read here ….!!!!!!
print(first_char)

  #run()
```

`first_char` must have first line of file `reddy.txt` but it is showing null

Comment: if you want read and write to a file then use `r+` not `w+`

Comment: I will write to file using compile function i.e  "w+" than I am trying to read using "r+" but even then that is not possible

Comment: Please tell us what error you get.

Comment: my compile fnction will compile Rahul .c using gcc and write error in reddy.txt file than after I must read the file and print the content of the file but I am unable to read the file once my compile function is done with writing

Comment: That's a description of your program; that is not an error message, traceback or anything. "unable to read" is too unclear, you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that `Popen` finishes the process, but it doesn't; `Popen` will merely *start* a process - and unless the compilation is *extremely* fast, it's quite likely that `reddy.txt` will be empty when you try to read it.

With Python 3.5+ you want `subprocess.run()`.

```
# Don't import *
from subprocess import run as s_run, PIPE, STDOUT
# Remove unused import
#import os

def compile():
    # Use a context manager
    with open("reddy.txt", "w+") as f:
        # For style points, avoid shell=True
        s_run(["gcc", "-c", "rahul.c "], stdout=f, stderr=STDOUT,
            # Check that the compilation actually succeeds
            check=True)

def run():
    compile()  # use the function we just defined instead of repeating youself
    p2 = s_run(["r.exe"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
        # Check that the process succeeds
        check = True,
        # Decode output from bytes() to str()
        universal_newlines=True)
    print(p2.stdout)

compile()
# Open file for reading, not writing!
with open("reddy.txt", "r") as f1:
    first_char = f1.readline()
print(first_char)
```

(I adapted the `run()` function along the same lines, though it's not being used in any of the code you posted.)

`first_char` is misleadingly named; `readline()` will read an entire line. If you want just the first byte, try

```
first_char = f1.read(1)
```

If you need to be compatible with older Python versions, try `check_output` or `check_call` instead of `run`.  If you are on 3.7+ you can use `text=True` instead of the older and slightly misleadingly named `universal_newlines=True`.

For more details about the changes I made, maybe see also [this](/a/51950538/874188).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the documentation on [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) you can see that when you use `w` to open a file, it will first truncate that files contents. Meaning there will be no output as you describe.

Since you only want to read the file you should use `r` in the open statement:

```
f1 = open("reddy.txt", "r")
```

Comment: It's not clear in the question where data is added to this file but if you manually check `reddy.txt` after a compile is there any data added?

Comment: I would use the `with` keyword and call wait on Popen. Otherwise your file may be closed before the process is finished: `with open("reddy.txt", "w+") as f: Popen("gcc -c rahul.c ",stdout=f,shell=True,stderr=STDOUT).wait()`

Comment: I have even tried using with but even then I am unable to read it

Comment: main intension of this program is to compile and run c program using python script

Comment: What do you  mean you are unable to read it after using `with`? Perhaps you can update your question with the other ways you have tried to help steer us towards a useful answer.

Comment: with open("reddy.txt", "w+") as f: Popen("gcc -c rahul.c ",stdout=f,shell=True,stderr=STDOUT).wait() even after using this syntax I am unable to read from the file

Comment: Have you tried deleting the txt file and re-running?